# Problema com link HTML com ASP clássico

Tags: html, asp, link

O seguinte trecho de código está me dando problemas:

```
 While not rsQuery.EOF
            If vStrCurso <> rsQuery("SIGLA") Then
                ind = ind & "<p></p>"
                ind = ind & "<span><b><a href='"&vStrParametro7&"/Busca/"&rsQuery("ID_CURSO")&"/' target='blank'>"&rsQuery("SIGLA")&" - "&rsQuery("DESCR")&"</a></b></span><br/>"
                ind = ind & "<span>- <a href='"&vStrParametro7&"/Busca/"&rsQuery("ID_CURSO")&"/'&#calendario target='blank'>"&rsQuery("DT_INICIO")&" à "&rsQuery("DT_FIM")&"</a></span>"
            Else
                ind = ind & "<br/><span>- <a href='"&vStrParametro7&"/Busca/"&rsQuery("ID_CURSO")&"/'&#calendario target='blank'>"&rsQuery("DT_INICIO")&" à "&rsQuery("DT_FIM")&"</a></span><br/>"
            End If
```

Não dá uma mensagem de erro, só não redireciona. Acredito que tenha algo errado com a barra e as aspas, já tentei varias vezes mas sem sucesso. Algo está errado. OBS: A página existe.

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não dá erro, só não redireciona. Acredito que tenha algo errado com a barra e as aspas no final antes do "target", já tentei varias vezes mas sem sucesso. Algo está errado.
OBS: A página existe.

Comment: @AndreeH descreva melhor a funcionalidade deste código, o que ele deveria fazer que não esta fazendo? poste um trecho maior do seu código que nos permita fazer testes e assim por diante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nessa parte:

```
 & #calendario "' target='blank'>" &
```

Você está tentando concatenar uma variável `#calendario`. Esse é um nome inválido para uma variável no VBScript, logo ela não pode existir.

Mesmo se ela fosse válida, está faltando o operador de concatenação de Strings (&) entre essa suposta variável e a próxima string.

```
#calendario "' target='blank'>" &
^ erro        ^ aqui falta o operador &
```

Se `#calendário` é na verdade uma âncora do link, então o código correto deveria ser:

```
ind = ind & "<span>- <a href='" & vStrParametro7 & "/Busca/" & rsQuery("ID_CURSO") & "/#calendario' target='blank'>" & rsQuery("DT_INICIO") & " à " &rsQuery("DT_FIM") & "</a></span>"
```

Comment: esse "#calendario" é uma parte da página para onde ira ser redirecionado ao clicar no link.
O link tem que ficar assim:
"www.seila.com.br/00000055/calendario".
O numero é o rsQuery("ID_CURSO"). até ai beleza, mas o resto não pega,

Comment: Editei minha resposta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Beleza, vou testar @MarcusVinicius. Obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou, valeu @MarcusVinicius